# Difference of Ionic Cordova vs Cordova commands

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been confused about the difference of building an apk using this commands:

ionic cordova build android

vs

cordova build android.

it seems that it has different output or file size when I look into debug apk on path

> /platform/android/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: Don't know much difference, but after upgrading to ionic 4, `cordova build android` not building new changes(UI or Features) to apk. but using `ionic cordova build android` show new change in apk and changes app size also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic ships with many built-in components, that in most cases gives a UX/UI closer to native components. This is the basic advantage of using ionic.

> The fact is, Ionic is built on top of Cordova, so you cannot argue that
>   ionic runs better than Cordova itself. Ionic is like **steroids** that you
>   can give to your Cordova apps.

[image]

**CLI**

It is always best advised to use Ionic CLI commands over Cordova when in an ionic environment. This is to ensure that ionic properly packs all its components/files alongside with Cordova and your app logic.

**Output Size**

APK/IPA sizes vary depending on the amount of logic included, let alone the code from your specific framework. If a simple Cordova app is 4mb, then ionic would be 4mb + size of ionic components. Frameworks like Angular has complex engines like [Ivy](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/07/what-is-angular-ivy/), that reduces the app build size, but those do not refactor anything related to Ionic or Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

`ionic cordova build android` is Like running `cordova build` directly, but also builds web assets with configuration from `ionic build` and provides friendly checks.

Check out the documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build)

Comment: so its better to use ionic cordova than cordova?

Comment: If you are using ionic it is better to use the recommended command for building it. Stick with the documentation of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova have own libraries so far and it is stable ionics also use them.

> https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/  Apache Cordova is an
>   open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use
>   standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for
>   cross-platform development. Applications execute within wrappers
>   targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API
>   bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data,
>   network status, etc.

ionic also using that libraries for there frameworks and developments so in that case

best approach is **why ionic use Cordova**

> Ionic, Cordova and PhoneGap are hybrid apps. ... They are written in
>   JavaScript but are rendered using native components, which means that
>   the user experience will generally be closer to other native apps,
>   because they will conform to the standards imposed by the operating
>   system
>
> https://www.netguru.com/blog/why-you-should-migrate-your-app-from-ionic-cordova-or-phonegap-to-react-native